# Setup a large wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, installation

I'm currently working on a project that involves setting up a large menu in WordPress. For this i've used the pages section in WordPres to create the pages in this menu and i added the top level pages to the menu section. The reason for this is that the client does not need to change the menu every time a page gets added. The menu picks it up automatically.

This gets a little tricky when i comes to stuff like a news section (where you want to show an overview of posts). For this i've created a custom meta box voor the page where the client can select an post or a category of posts to display on that page. Also the menu contains quite a few items with the same info like a contact section or a route description for example. What i want is that this information is entered once and used on the different pages in the menu. That's were the custom metabox for the pages comes in handy again.

Now for the question... and maybe thats a matter of opinion, but i can't help but wonder if the above approach is the way to go... using only pages and a lot of custom scripts.

Anyone got experience with this?
Thanks for the help.

Cheer,
J

Comment: I'd suggest you to add some samples of the code you're using. Without that, it's kind of an abstract proposition...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can post some code if you like but it's not really a code question. I'ts really about the best approach to setup a large WordPress website. Do you use only pages and custom templates or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: WordPress provides nice tools to deal with lots of scenarios (back and frontend). The one you are describing seems ok. It's hard to tell if there's a better method without having details of what you are doing. Is your issue populating the menu with items selected in the meta box of each page? . . . . Just trying to make sense of what's your real question.

Answer (score 0):

Menu feature in new wordpress is good approach to configure menu.
But if you like to change menu every time user add page, you can use old menu style on wordpress, the code like

`<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>`

Just check this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages